# Discord JDA IdLong Arraylist<Arraylist<Long>

Tags: java, arraylist, discord-jda

I'm trying to figure out how can i store Long info about a Discord user in an array.

Tommy on discord type: ;create
then
Mike on discord type : ;create

```
public class Create extends ListenerAdapter {
  public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    if (!event.isFromGuild()) return;
    String[] messageSent = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" "); //for further code
    String name = event.getMember().getUser().getName();
    long idLong = event.getMember().getUser().getIdLong();
    String idString = event.getMember().getUser().getId(); //not for Stackoverflow question
    long base = 1L; //everyone start with 1 (L is because we are using Long version of int value)
    if (messageSent[0].equalsIgnoreCase(";Create")) {
        ArrayList<Long> dcbase = new ArrayList<>(); //Long is used to store getIdLong value
        dcbase.add(idLong); //
        dcbase.add(base); // 1L is default value
        event.getChannel().sendMessage("Here is the array "+ dcbase).queue();}}
```

Now the problem is if i want my ArrayList to be for many user I would need an ArrayList of ArrayList. `Arraylist<ArrayList<Long>>`
But to search through them I would like to do search using the `IdLong` value.
I tried to replace `dcbase` as `idLong` but its already defined.

Is there any way i can do that?

Because what i want to do next is have a method that goes to the idLong of Tommy and pull out the [1] of the Tommy ArrayList.

I plan to store the info to a file that way and will have longer Arrays:

```
177877878787 1 0 0 //Tommy IdLong, base Long, stuff i'll add, stuff i'll add 
121244777778 1 //Mike IdLong, base Long
//New line for new member.
```

Since I don't know on which line the required IdLong will be stored in the file, i need a reference to search it.
I am self-thaught, I hope I am clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `Map`. The key is the user id (as a `long`) and the value is your number:

```java
private final Map<Long, Long> map = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
  ...
  map.put(id, base);
  ...
}
```

You can then simply access the value by using `map.get(id)`. Instead of using lists, I would recommend using proper objects with defined fields for whatever data you want to store.

For the case of persistence, instead of just writing your data to some file, use a relational database like [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) or [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). This way you can easily update them at runtime without having to read/write the entire map every time you want to access it.

A very helpful thing to use for this is the [Java Persistence API (JPA)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/index.htm).

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class UserInfo {
  @Id
  private long id;
  private long base;

  public UserInfo(long id, long base) {
    this.id = id;
    this.base = base;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public long getId() { return this.id; }

  public void setBase(long base) {
    this.base = base;
  }

  public long getBase() { return this.base; }
}
```

Comment: So much useful informations. Thank you . I will look into it.